# How to run one JSF WAR file in second JSF project?

Tags: java, jsf, war

I am working on project in JSF, using Tomcat 7. The application will have two parts - the presentation and the administration, main part is about the administration. What I want to do is to create something like a web library.

To have this more clear, I'll try to show structure of the project:

```
The main application project (let's call it admin) that is builed into WAR file.
Second project using the first one (let's call it presentation).
Presentation is using the admin WAR file.
both projects are typical JSFs - admin has pages, beans, etc.
```

In NetBeans, I have no problem with adding WAR file as a library, but, there are two things. The first: are all ManagedBeans in *admin* initialized together with *presentation* run, so I can use them in *presentation*? The second: how do I access pages from *presentation* that are located in *admin*?

Maybe I am wrong about this idea and I should use different way how to achieve this - so just tell me please.

Also, I probably will not be able to deploy two war files and run them - most of the hostings where the application will run allow deploying of one WAR file only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a common JAR instead of WAR, so that you can include it in both WARs. This way you can share managed beans and templates between both WARs. The Facelets resources can just be placed in `/META-INF/resources` of the JAR. The JSF artifacts like managed beans will be auto-discovered if you provide a `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` file.

#### See also:

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738)

Comment: hmm, finally I have decided I won't make it more complicated than it has to be, so I will use old way. Anyway thanks, I might find this useful in future.

Comment: More complicated? It's IMHO less complicated than having a WAR in WAR which is technically wrong.

Comment: I mean I have chosen completely different solution (with one WAR only).