# Can the index.xhtml be stored in an external JAR file? What would be its URL?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jar, facelets

I'd like to have all the facelets and managed bean into one external jar, but if I put de index.xhtml there I don't konw how to reference it.

If the jar structure is:

```
 IndexManagedBean.class
 META-INF/
    resources/
       pages/
          index.xhtml
```

What is its URL?

Comment: Please do not mix JSF 1.2 and 2.0 tags. Are you using JSF 1.2 or 2.0? I'll assume JSF 2.0, but you need to remove the JSF 1.2 tag. It'll only confuse the answerers because JSF 1.x and 2.x usually require different answers.

Comment: Given the fact that the answer works for you, you're using JSF 2.0. I've edited your question and removed the JSF 1.2 tag. In the future questions, please be more careful with the tags. Don't introduce ambiguity in the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the JAR is placed in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and that you're using JSF 2.x and that webapp's context path is `/contextpath`, and the `FacesServlet` is mapped on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` then you can reference it by the following URL:

> http://example.com/contextpath/pages/index.xhtml

#### See also

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)