# JSF: Serving Resources From a Jar

Tags: jsf, facelets

I´m in the process to create a couple of jars packed with facelets templates for usage through the organisation.

Stuck in JSF 1.2 this functionality does not come out of the box.
Stack:

- Jboss EAP 5.1
- Seam 2.2
- Richfaces 3.3.3

It seems to me that I primarily need two resources:

1. Resource resolver that finds Faclets resources
2. A thing that serve css and js resources from a jar

Resource resolver seems to be the easy part:
http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/create-common-facelets-jar/

The thing that streams css / js is slightly more complicated:
**JSF: Serving Resources From a Jar**
http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2006/05/09/jsf_serving_resources_from_a/

- Phaselistener
- Filter
- Servlet
- Weblets

I would very much like to use Weblets as it seems to be project dedicated to solve this problem. Furthermore it is recommended in this cool JSF book i bought: "Pro JSF and Ajax
Building Rich Internet Components"

**The problem is that I can not find a stable release in any Maven repo and no documentation. In the example no faclets is not used:**

https://github.com/werpu/weblets

In the article above a Filter is highlighted as a good solution.
http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/filter/ExtensionsFilter.html

Sadly it is not a simple task to hook in to this solution. I simply do not have the time (or knowledge at the moment) :(

Possible I can use this project: http://jawr.java.net/introduction.html
Jawr aims to bundle js and css files.

The project wiki indicates that it could be possible:
http://jawr.java.net/docs/generators.html see the "classpath resource generator" section.

Please advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello i you would like to load css, js etc from a jar you could use the following.

```
package se.lu.ldc.core.servlet;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


/**
 * Servlet för att hämta diverse filer från jar om de finns i jaren
 *  jpg, png, gif, css, xcss,xml,js
 * @author ldc-jha
 *
 */
@WebServlet(name="ldcServlet",loadOnStartup=1,urlPatterns={"*.jpg","*.png","*.gif","*.css","*.xcss","*.js"})
public class LDCFrameWorkServlet extends HttpServlet
{  

    //where the files are in the jar.
    public final String BASE_PATH = "xhtml/framework";

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("INIT()");
        super.init(config);
    }
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        /* if this servlet is not mapped to a path, use the request URI */
        String path = request.getPathInfo();
        if (path == null) {
            path = request.getRequestURI().substring(
                    request.getContextPath().length());
        }

        URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
        getResource(BASE_PATH+"/"+path.substring(1));

        if (resource == null) {
            ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

            String filename = sc.getRealPath(path);
            log.info("During Load:"+resource+":"+path+":"+filename);
            try{
                resource = sc.getResource(path);
            }catch(Exception e){}
            if(resource == null)
            {
                response.sendError(404, path + " denied");

            }

        }
        /* failure conditions */
        if (path.endsWith(".seam")) {
            javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet facesServlet = new FacesServlet();
            facesServlet.service(request, response);

            return;
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".class")) {
            response.sendError(403, path + " denied");
            return;
        }

        /* find the resource */
        log.info("Looking for " + path + " on the classpath");

        //response.sendError(404, path + " not found on classpath");

        log.info("found " + path + " on the classpath:"+resource.toString());

        /* check modification date */
        URLConnection connection = resource.openConnection();
        long lastModified = connection.getLastModified();
        long ifModifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Modified-Since");
        if (ifModifiedSince != -1 && lastModified <= ifModifiedSince) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            return;
        }

        /* write to response */
        response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(path));
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                response.getOutputStream(), 512);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                resource.openStream(), 512);
        try {
            int len;
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            while ((len = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
            in.close();
            if (connection.getInputStream() != null) {
                connection.getInputStream().close();
            }
        }

    } /* doGet() */


    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

if you want to load faclets from a jar you could use a Custom DefaultResourceResolver

```
/**
 * Används för hämta hämta xhtml filer från jar filen
 * @author ldc-jha
 *
 */
public class ClassletsResourceResolver extends DefaultResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver{

    public ClassletsResourceResolver() {
        super();
    }

    private static final String PREFIX = "/framework/";
    private static final String LAYOUT = "/layout/";

    public String getPrefix() {
        return PREFIX;
    }

    public URL resolveUrl(String path) {
        final String prefix = getPrefix();
        System.out.println("resolveUrl()"+path);
        URL url = null;
        if (path != null && path.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
            final String resource = path.substring(PREFIX.length());
            url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xhtml/framework/"+resource);
        }

        if (path != null && path.startsWith(LAYOUT)) {
            System.out.println("LAYOUT:"+path);
            url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xhtml/framework"+path);
            System.out.println(url);
        }

        if(url != null){
            return url;
        }
        else
        {
            return super.resolveUrl(path);
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to load the resourceResolver wihtout editing your xhtml you can do this.

```
@WebListener
public class SimpleServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    private static final LogProvider log = Logging.getLogProvider(SimpleServletContextListener.class);


    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){


                      event.getServletContext().setAttribute("facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER","se.lu.ldc.core.reslover.ClassletsResourceResolver");

}
```

}

You might have to let Seam know about the Faclets as well, let me know if there is any problem.  i had the same idea, and got it working with packing all css, xhtml etc in a jar.

Comment: Note that when you're using JSF 2.0, this all is then unnecessary. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code It's by the way strange that you're using JSF 1.x on a Servlet 3.0 environment. Why not just upgrading to JSF 2.x immediately?

Comment: As I Said: "Stuck in JSF 1.2 this functionality does not come out of the box."

Comment: The stack is a supported boundle from jboss (jboss eap). Fiddling with would break the support agreement. So Im told anyway.

Comment: jsf 2 isn't compatible with seam 2 until version 2.3.

Comment: Remember you would have to add pages.xml and page.xml. if you like to i can add that aswell.

Comment: Trind, I think so, just fuddling with som maven issues right now, Ill get back to u.