# JSF project how to show xhtml file from one of its dependencies

Tags: java, jsf, maven

I'm trying to create a common error page that can be used across many projects.

I'm trying to create a separate project called ErrorProject. All of my other projects will have a Maven dependency to this ErrorProject.

Let's say that I have created project A and there is an error, how can I show an xhtml page from ErrorProject when using project A in the browser?

Currently I have this in the `web.xml` of project A and `error.xhtml` is a page in the ErrorProject.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do it with Maven, but to the point, you need to tell it somehow to accomplish the structure as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it your error project a **web project** which creates a war? If it is just put the `/error.xhtml` into `src/main/webapp`. Then you can add the dependency and [Maven will do an overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), including it into main application's web root directory, so you can reference it from `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I didn't have `<type>war</type><scope>runtime</scope>` in my dependency.