# Core JSF2 Project reusable for other projects [JAR]

Tags: java, maven, jsf-2, composite-component

I created a project with many Abstract and Generic classes to work with and some composite components. I changed the packing to JAR and used it as a maven dependency for another projects.

So, everything on server side is working. Spring injects my classes and stuff.. But the composite components isn´t found. I search around stackoverflow, and saw some errors referencing the JARs dirs. But I don´t know if I put the composite component on the core project at the correct dir. This is the path I added it (normally, as if it was a client-project):

```
  - br
       - main
              - webapp
                     - resources
                              - myCompositeFolder
```

Is it correct?
How do I change maven packing to make it work?

I also want to ask another thing... I have to costumize composite component 'injecting' some extra code from the client-project. To do that, I did something like this on the component:

```
<ui:include src="/filters/extraFilters.xhtml" />
```

and that file (extraFilters) will be located on the client-project webapp folder.
I tested on the same project, it worked. Just don´t know if it will work loading from a JAR!

Comment: Non-maven answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/8320738#8320738 Key is thus: they should ultimately end up in `/META-INF/resources` of JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer BalusC. I´ll try to do it manually and see what happends, I´ll post the answer here in a bit.

Comment: I tried that, created the META-INF and put the resources there... But on maven install, it didn´t bring the subfolders [resources/myCompositeFolder]. Brought the folder with a folder named 'maven' and the 'MANIFEST.MF' :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work without the WAR.

Thanks to Visola (http://bearprogrammer.com/). The solution was:
but the composite folder inside the parent (core) project:

```
 src\resources\META-INF\resources
```

And , done! All in one JAR!

Thanks BalusC, Visola and Jin!

Comment: @BalusC's point seems right, apparently. You have to re-accept your own answer not mine.

Comment: Both are true. Good answers. Should be a way to make both acceptable.