# Set HTTP headers properly to force caching on JS, CSS and PNG files

Tags: jsf, glassfish, servlet-filters, browser-cache

How can I tell to GlassFish server, to store all JS, CSS and PNG files into browser cache in order to reduce HTTP GET requests?

I am using JSF and PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make use of JSF builtin resource handler. I.e. use [`<h:outputStylesheet name>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html), [`<h:outputScript name>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`<h:graphicImage name>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) with files in `/resources` folder instead of "plain vanilla" `<link rel="stylesheet">`, `<script>` and `<img>`.

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="images/logo.png" />
```

This way you don't need to worry about resource caching at all. JSF builtin resource handler has already set the necessary response headers. The expiration time defaults already to 1 week.

In Mojarra you can control the expiration time by the following context parameter (the value is in millis):

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks. -->
</context-param>
```

And in MyFaces:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks. -->
</context-param>
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. But looking at the HTTP server monitor on netbeans, i noticed the file that takes more time to download is primefaces.js , and i never call that script in my pages...

Comment: PrimeFaces components do.

Comment: Yes, primefaces components, generates HTML+js code , and averytime i refresh the page, a GET request is called to download primefaces.js , jquery.js and so on... This files are not in /resources folder so how can i tell "store those files in cache memory" ?

Comment: Those **are** JSF resource dependencies. They are bundled in PrimeFaces JAR file (for detail, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8320486/). Look closer at the HTTP traffic. If you don't refresh but just navigate to another page which also needs that file, then browser won't request it at all. If you refresh the page, then the browser will indeed send a GET request, but the server will return a 304 response without body. Only if you perform a "hard refresh" then it'll be a 200 response and contain the file in the body.

Comment: & how do you force caching on images referenced in css files? there we can't use things like `<h:grephicImage>`..

Comment: @user01: They will be if you use `#{resource}`.

Comment: any other ways? I don't really like putting EL in css or js files.

Comment: also I think that increases *some* work for JSF if I have considerably large no of images in css

Comment: @user01: consider OmniFaces `UnmappedResourceHandler`. Otherwise, bite the bullet, fix them all and learn the lesson for next JSF project. Hint: Eclipse has builtin regexp find&replace.

Comment: noobs (like me) should also be aware that having the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context-param set to "Development" (in `web.xml`), _seems_ to disable caching.