# Google Chrome Audit says "The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable" on JSF resources from library

Tags: css, jsf, google-chrome-devtools, http-caching

I used Chrome's auditing feature to try to find some performance bottlenecks in my web site.  I found a lot of reports of non-cacheable resources.

I did a dry run with a single-page containing a stylesheet in a library and found the same thing:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="style.css"/> 
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div><h:outputText value="test"/></div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here's the audit log entry:

```
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:
    style.css.jsf
```

The interesting thing is, if I remove it from the library, this message goes away.  So, it looks like there is a problem with caching resources in libraries.

Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: According to one of the comments in this answer, perhaps CSS is not cached if a normal refresh is performed on the page:  [Set HTTP headers properly to force caching on JS, CSS and PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389842/set-http-headers-properly-to-force-caching-on-js-css-and-png-files)

Can that be right?  Why can't a bookmark or typed in URL re-used the cached copy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a false error.

The `library` attribute adds the library value as a query string, see also [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) Chrome Audit appears to penalize **any** query string in the resource URL, even though the response headers and actual browser behavior during refreshs are completely valid. I just tried on my own Chrome and I can indeed see this false error too.

If you tab back to "Network" tab, then you must notice valid `Expires`, `ETag` and `Last-Mofidied` response headers (and no `Cache-Control`) and you must observe the below browser behavior:

- On a fresh request in empty cache, or on hard reloading the page via Ctrl+F5, you must see a HTTP status of 200 on those resources.
- On navigating to another page referencing exactly same resources, or on clicking exactly same (bookmark) link again, or on pressing Enter in browser's address bar once again, you must see a grayed out HTTP status of 200 and a "from cache" in size column.
- On reloading the page via F5 or Ctrl+R, you must see a HTTP status of 304 on those resources (and the browser will receive a much smaller response — only the response headers, no body — and continue using the cached version).

If those resources were really "explicitly non-cacheable" as literally mentioned by Chrome Audit, you'd have seen a full HTTP 200 response in each single case.

Query strings in resource URLs are often used as cache busting technique. When a resource is updated in server side, then the developer of course want to force a fresh reload in client side. One way is renaming the resource path/filename, but another and more common way is changing a query string parameter value (usually, the one representing a version or timestamp).

Try a more decent web performance testing tool. E.g. YSlow. In my case, it didn't flip on query strings in resource URLs.

Comment: Verified this in its entirety.  Perfectly explained.  Thank you!

Comment: [Relevant Chromium issue.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80139)