# My js/css caching is not working even after using project stage and filters, header date always getting update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to implement caching for my JS/CSS files but it is not working, I am using Mojarra JSF-2.2.12 and PrimeFaces 6.

I have tried using javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE as Production and created a custom filter but nothing worked.

Need your help... below is web.xml code snippet

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
<param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 8 hours -->  
</context-param>
```

In xhtml we have written like below.

```
<h:outputScript name="js/ProcessSpecific-min.js"></h:outputScript>
```

It looks like response server header is updating date and time on every hit, may be that is the reason it is not able to pick it from cache.
[header response for 1 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhPyM.png)

Comment: JSF2 is an 'api' version. Please state your explicit version (2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.x) And off-topic, your 'library' usesage is not 'correct': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: I am using JSF-2.2.12 and above mentioned library belong to my custom war, it is under web/resources/js

Comment: Read the link I posted again... you should not use css/js/images in the library part, but give your library a name and use the css/js/images in the other attrbibute

Comment: I have done as per your suggestion, but still it is not working, can you please check screen what I have attached from header, it may give some more idea of the issue.

Comment: And **what** date-time is modified each time? I see an expires header in the future (almost 1.5 month). So that seems normal. How do you conclude caching is not working? And tried different browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set HTTP headers properly to force caching on JS, CSS and PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389842/set-http-headers-properly-to-force-caching-on-js-css-and-png-files)

Comment: Hi Hamid it is not duplicate to your link because I am already doing what is there in that answer but issue is not resolved, and in my case request header of the fiile is getting updated every time whenever I am hitting the URL because of this cache not working.

Comment: @Kukeltje I am checking in chrome browser and it is always showing 200 code with data size and also date in request header for that file always shows as current date time.

Answer (score 0):

you use Mojarra or Myfaces ?

In Mojarra you can control the expiration time by the following context parameter (the value is in millis):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks. -->
</context-param>
```

And in MyFaces:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES</param-name>
    <param-value>3628800000</param-value> <!-- 6 weeks. -->
</context-param>
```

[Set HTTP headers properly to force caching on JS, CSS and PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389842/set-http-headers-properly-to-force-caching-on-js-css-and-png-files)

Comment: I am already doing what you have suggested and also updated my question.

Comment: @Hamidrostami: If you think this is the answer and the answer you refer to is a full duplicate, then please click the 'flag' below the question and suggest marking it as a duplicate instead of sort of partially copying the other answer.

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you for help . i am new in stackoverflow. i think it is duplicate question.

Comment: @Kukeltje , as I replied earlier, it may look like duplicate but it is not if you check the issue which I have replied to you. Issue is of request header date attribute.

Comment: I'm not saying it is or is not, I explicitly stated that _"if you **think** this is the answer..."_ helping @hamidrostami and explain how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: i undrestood what you are saying.thank you. I thought it is duplicate question but i was wrong.