# How to include a xhtml from an external jar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm doing a project with JSF. I have created a page that displays information
about some movies. Everything works so far. Now I want to implement the possibilty
to display information about tv series as well. For this I'd like to bin everything
that has do with displaying movies into a subproject that will produce a .jar-file 
which I then will include in my main project. For the tv series I'll make the same
thing.

At the moment I have just this one project and it's structered like this (I show 
only the relevant parts):

```
wgmdb.war
 \_ src
     \_ main
         \_ webapp
             \_ view
                 \_ overview.xhtml
                 \_ movies
                     \_ details.xhtml
```

In my overview.xhtml I include details.xhtml like this:

My goal is something achieve now something like the following, where wgmdb-movies.jar
is a library included by the main project:

```
wgmdb.war
 \_ src
     \_ main
         \_ webapp
             \_ view
                 \_ overview.xhtml

wgmdb-movies.jar
 \_ src
     \_ main
         \_ resources
             \_ details.xhtml
```

The problem is now, that I have now idea how to include details.xhtml from the library
into the overview.xhtml of the main project. What src path must I use that details.xhtml
will be found?

Best regards,

metalhamster

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `details.xhtml` has to end up like `/META-INF/resources/details.xhtml` in the JAR. This way you'll be able to just use `<ui:include src="details.xhtml">`.

In Maven perspective, that would be `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/details.xhtml`.

#### See also:

- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for every file, except for one... For movie_cover.xhtml I get javax.faces.FacesException: Error Checking Last Modified for jndi:/server/wgmdb/view//oauth-v2-spec/movie_cover.xhtml although movie_cover.xhtml is in the same directory as overview.xhtml and is included exactly the same.

Comment: I know, but I have no idea were it comes from. For the other files it doesn't happen. For me it looks like the <ui:include src="movie_cover.xhtml"/> in overview.xhtml searches for the source in the same directory and doesn't find the file...

Comment: Well, then it's either a typo in path or actual file or a build fail.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. The file was include in another place as well and there I included it differently with another slash before the actual path with resulted in the double slash. ;-)