# Modular Webdevelopment Java

Tags: java, jsf, plugins, module, modular

I plan to develop a Java Webapplication with Primefaces, JSF, EJB / JPA etc.
That application should be modular, so i can attach new programparts during the runtime. Just like in Wordpress (I love that Plug-in behaviour!).

---

**In example**, i have a Kindergarden-management application. 
The base version can only handle the Kids, Groups and Staff. (Web-Frontend & Persistence, etc.)

Then a few weeks later, the Kindergarden want a Toy-Management Feature. Inside the Toy-Management-Plugin they could assign Toys to groups (they are managed in the base program). So i develop the Toy-Management Plugin  (With Web-Frontend, it's Persistence for the Toy-Tables, etc.). The Kindergarden puts that Plugin (.jar) into a central plugin-directory and it registers itself in the NavigationMenu. 
Now, the Kindergarden could navigate between Kids, Groups, Staff and Toys.

Later, they want some other stuff, i develop, send, and they put in that plugin directory. They see it in their Menu and can work with it.

---

**Is it possible** to have a WAR-Glassfish-WebApplication that is expanded that way? Each Plugin has it's own Database-Management, so i never have to change anything on the base-program?

What techniques would you recommend?

- [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/)
- [JSPF](https://code.google.com/p/jspf/)
- [This? (currently my favorite)](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.de/2013/12/modular-jsf-applications.html)
- Or something complete new?

Unfortunately all blogposts, Stackoverflow-Questions & -Answers, tutorials are many years old. Is something complete new out there that no one has taken notice of, because all the old-Posts-Answers-Questions are flooding the google-search-result-list?

Comment: Related / possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code

Comment: What a pleasure to have you here BalusC!
I already read that answer a couple of times, but unfortunately i think i have a problem in understanding where i would drop my finished stand-alone jar-plugins, EJBs and POJOs.


Do you have a link to another explaination of that solution?

Comment: It's basically same as "This?" as in your question. This is indeed not really for "plugins" the way as you've in mind. It's more for component libraries like PrimeFaces/OmniFaces/etc. For real plugins, OSGi would be a better fit (Eclipse is also one and all OSGi via Equinox, by the way, as is GlassFish), but I don't have hands on experience with it, so I can tell only very little about it.