# Jsf component reference in two projects

Tags: jsf-2.2, modularity

For modularity we wanted to separate out application based on funcitons to modular projects. 
We are having issues with accessing managed beans in a different project.

Can we access a jsf page in one project A to a backing bean in another project B without creating a jar of project B?

What are the possible options?

There is no common code between 2 projects. We want to keep ui components in project A and backing components in project B. 
Post to an action from A to B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)

Comment: You can't... Not directly. Any 'inter-app' communication would work. Be it server side via jms or client-side by calling a rest-service directly from the browser.