# How to use a JSF template in multiple java web applications?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jar, facelets

Is it possible to use a JSF template created in a java web application, and use it in others java web applications? How can i achieve this?

Actually, i have the same footer and header code in all web applications and the content its dynamic (managed bean, etc.), not static HTML. We are using JSF 2.1 and JBoss EAP 6.3. Thank you!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code

Comment: Jasper, BalusC. We have multiple java web application projects and i want to use one web application as a template for the others web applications deployed in the JBoss Server, not a JAR.

Comment: The multiple projects parts was clear. For what reason can't you use a JAR?

Comment: Because in the header we use a @ManagedBean, but i think we can resolve that with faces-config.xml in the JAR. Thank you!