# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: increment

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In order to cleanup and refactor some code I created a new workspace and also new project(s). My project setup is as follows: One core-project (Javaproject using Maven for dependency management) and two dynamic web projects (JSF) that both share code from the core project (similar setup to [this SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)). I'm using Wildfly 10 with Hibernate and Primefaces.
What I've done so far is copying essential classes from my old messy project to the new core project in order to get the application up and running. The code hasn't been touched and it was working fine in my old setup. The application starts fine and navigates to the login-page but every time I hit the login-button I receive following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: increment
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.makeIdGenerator(BinderHelper.java:641)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processId(AnnotationBinder.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2251)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 68 more
```

The `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: increment` should actually not occure since everything is annotated fine and has been working fine.
Interestingly also the DB-tables are not created automatically as they actually should. At first I thought it could be due to colliding dependencies such as JPA because in the deployed `WEB-INF\lib` folder of the web projects I find a bunch of unnecessary jars like jboss* and hibernate* etc. Deleting them unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Example model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findUserByEmail", query = "select u from User u where u.email = :email")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    public static final String FIND_BY_EMAIL = "User.findUserByEmail";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "PK_user_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_user_id")
    private List<ArticleList> articleLists;

    @Column(name = "user_email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "user_first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "user_hashed_password")
    private byte[] hashedPassword;

    @Column(name = "user_last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "user_salt")
    private byte[] salt;

    //getters and setters
}
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="toyjoPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>de.jb.toyjo.model.Article</class>
        <class>de.jb.toyjo.model.ArticleList</class>
        <class>de.jb.toyjo.model.Category</class>
        <class>de.jb.toyjo.model.TextModule</class>
        <class>de.jb.toyjo.model.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toyjodb_tcs?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any clues why this happens? Thanks already in advance

Edit: I tried as @Rohit Gaikwad mentioned but now getting this error:

```
10:47:36,006 INFO  [stdout] (default task-35) Error while running query: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

10:47:36,007 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

10:47:36,008 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)

10:47:36,008 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)

10:47:36,009 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:560)

10:47:36,009 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at de.jb.toyjo.dao.GenericDAO.findOneResult(GenericDAO.java:130)

10:47:36,010 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at de.jb.toyjo.dao.UserDAO.findUserByEmail(UserDAO.java:23)

10:47:36,010 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at de.jb.toyjo.facade.UserFacade.isValidLogin(UserFacade.java:14)

10:47:36,011 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at de.jb.toyjo.bean.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:24)

10:47:36,011 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

10:47:36,011 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

10:47:36,012 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

10:47:36,012 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

10:47:36,013 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)

10:47:36,013 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)

10:47:36,014 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)

10:47:36,014 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

10:47:36,015 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

10:47:36,015 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)

10:47:36,015 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)

10:47:36,016 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)

10:47:36,016 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)

10:47:36,017 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

10:47:36,017 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)

10:47:36,017 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)

10:47:36,018 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)

10:47:36,018 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)

10:47:36,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

10:47:36,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

10:47:36,019 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)

10:47:36,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

10:47:36,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

10:47:36,020 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at de.jb.toyjo.filter.LoginCheckFilter.doFilter(LoginCheckFilter.java:84)

10:47:36,021 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

10:47:36,021 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

10:47:36,021 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

10:47:36,022 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

10:47:36,022 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

10:47:36,023 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

10:47:36,023 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,023 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

10:47:36,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

10:47:36,024 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

10:47:36,025 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

10:47:36,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

10:47:36,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

10:47:36,026 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

10:47:36,027 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,027 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,028 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

10:47:36,028 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,029 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

10:47:36,029 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

10:47:36,029 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

10:47:36,030 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

10:47:36,030 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

10:47:36,031 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

10:47:36,031 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

10:47:36,032 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

10:47:36,032 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

10:47:36,033 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

10:47:36,033 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

10:47:36,034 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

10:47:36,034 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

10:47:36,034 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

10:47:36,035 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

10:47:36,035 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

10:47:36,036 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)

10:47:36,036 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

10:47:36,036 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

10:47:36,037 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

10:47:36,038 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35) Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

10:47:36,038 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)

10:47:36,039 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)

10:47:36,039 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)

10:47:36,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)

10:47:36,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)

10:47:36,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)

10:47:36,041 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)

10:47:36,041 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)

10:47:36,041 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)

10:47:36,042 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)

10:47:36,042 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)

10:47:36,043 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)

10:47:36,043 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)

10:47:36,044 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)

10:47:36,045 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)

10:47:36,045 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)

10:47:36,046 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)

10:47:36,046 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)

10:47:36,047 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)

10:47:36,047 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)

10:47:36,048 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)

10:47:36,049 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)

10:47:36,049 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)

10:47:36,050 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)

10:47:36,050 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)

10:47:36,051 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)

10:47:36,051 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)

10:47:36,052 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)

10:47:36,052 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)

10:47:36,052 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)

10:47:36,053 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   ... 67 more

10:47:36,054 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35) Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 41444D49

10:47:36,055 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)

10:47:36,055 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)

10:47:36,055 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)

10:47:36,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)

10:47:36,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)

10:47:36,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-35)   ... 96 more
```

Comment: In which model, do you have "increment" property? Can you also share your model?

Comment: I added the User class which is the only relevant class at this stage of the worklflow. But all of my model classes have the same `@GenericGenerator`. Again, this was working fine in my previous setup

Comment: Have you tried using `@GeneratedValue` with it's defaults and no `@GenericGenerator`?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and afaik MySQL has no such thing like sequences

Comment: I changed that comment about sequences when you weren't looking. But maybe if you've updated the Hibernate version it would cause it if you have multiple generators by the same name. Each one is supposed to be unique, and only used in one class or superclass.

Comment: I tried just using `@GeneratedValue` but still get the same error. I also deleted every other model class and just left the User class and everything else that is essential for this step but still the same. I'm pretty sure i is due to some version clash of hibernate and/or jpa but I don't know how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

- The problem is `byte[]` to `String` conversion at the time of de-serialization. SHA produces raw byte array and there is no guarantee that arbitrary `byte[]` will produce valid `String`, irrespective to encoding.   Thus your code was only working by **accident**.
- Instead of `byte[]` make use of `String` for`hashedPassword` and `salt`.  If this worked then the issue was of mapping `byte[]` with hibernate.

**Note:** keep your code of generating primary key using `increment` as it is.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this earlier and what it does is creating a new table in my database named "e_id". After hitting login I now receive `Error while running query: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize`. I can't emphasize this enough: I don't think it's a matter of code since the exact same code was working fine for months

Comment: Maybe you have changed your database, I guess now you are using oracle db. please add your entire stack `org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize`

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm still using MySQL

Comment: Both didn't work. I updated my question and added the `SerializationException` stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `@Lob` annotation but that's unrelated to the problem. It also didn't change anything. Using `AUTO` only has the effect, that now there is an additional table in my database called `hibernate_sequence`

Comment: `@Lob` may not solve the issue but you have issue of converting Binary Data To A String. i.e, at the time of de-serialization. check here http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/ . instead of `byte[]` make use of `String` for `hashedPassword` and `salt`

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions in various combinations and none of them worked. But thanks a lot anyways. I think we are heading in the wrong direction because this code was fine and is approved. Maybe the binary to string conversion is not best practise but it has no impact on the initial problem. Again, I'm sure it has to do with some clashing libraries as this often happens when wildfly internal libraries clash with their external counterpart